# How to perform a cross-search from mysql database with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Basicly I want to perform a cross search from a mysql database with PHP. I really don't know how to put it in any other way. Let's say we got a select query

```
    'SELECT id_tag FROM `'._DB_PREFIX_.'projekt_rooms` WHERE id_product = '.$productid.'';
```

So that row returns me all the values from the database where id_product matches. However how can I perform a query to return me all the id_product's that match the id_tag's after that. Should i put it in a loop or is there any other way and how ?

Here is a picture to clarify the table.

[image]

BR's

Comment: Why "after that"? Can't you do sth like `WHERE  id_product = '.$productid.' AND id_product = id_tag`?

Comment: As you can see from the image the query will return multiple/different tag id's and I really cant see a way to get all of the associated products of the same tag's with one single query.

Comment: It can be done using a subquery.  See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly (you want all products that have the same tag_id as the product(s) specified by `$productid`),  you should wrap a query around your query (making it a subquery), something like this...

```
'select id_product 
from `'._DB_PREFIX_.'projekt_rooms` where id_tag in 
   (SELECT id_tag 
     FROM `'._DB_PREFIX_.'projekt_rooms` WHERE id_product = '.$productid.');'
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks a lot. Was giving me a headache :)